# Allowing sshd on local network without access to internet

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, webserver

I have setup `sshd` on my server and can access it fine from both my local network and remotely from other networks. I set up port forwarding using a different port than port `22`. Port forwarding is setup on my router to forward to the new port. I also enabled `ufw` firewall. All was working fine. Today my internet went out and I wanted to `ssh` into the server while on my local network but was unable to. I tried disabling `ufw` but was still unable to connect. I'm guessing the problem has something to do with my `sshd_config` file or port forwarding on my router. My `sshd_config` file is setup to listen only to the port I am forwarding to. I have not changed the default `ListenAddress`. Do I need to change that to allow access to my local network?

Comment: I just found out that if I turn my cable modem off when the internet is out then I am able to connect through ssh just fine. I guess I have everything configured properly. Does anyone have any idea why having the cable modem on when the internet goes out would prevent ssh into my server when I'm on the same local network? Is there a way to tell if my ssh connection is trying to go out over the internet or staying on my lan?

Comment: What command/program are you using to ssh? I'm guessing you are using the machine's local IP?